# Setting a Variable to a string returning as Null

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have These Variables at the moment

```
var rsCash = 0;
var rsCashString = rsCash.toString();
var rsCashLength = rsCashString.length;
```

I am using the rsCash Variable in a Switch Statement and i need the length of the number but i am getting  the Error Message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Here is the Switch Statement

```
switch (rsCashLength){
case 1:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash + "Gp";
    break;
case 2:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash + "Gp";
    break;
case 3:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash + "Gp";
    break;
case 4:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash.substring(0,cut1) + "k";
    break;
case 5:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash.substring(0,cut2) + "k";
    break;
case 6:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash.substring(0,cut3) + "k";
    break;
case 7:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash.substring(0,cut1) + "M";
    break;
case 8:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash.substring(0,cut2) + "M";
    break;
case 9:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash.substring(0,cut3) + "M";
    break;
case 10:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash.substring(0,cut4) + "M";
    break;
case 11:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash.substring(0,cut5) + "M";
    break;
```

}

I have Tried

```
Switch (rsCash.toString().length){
```

I also have a Switch Statement which changes the rsCash Variable like this

```
switch (RewardNumber){
case 1:
    rsCash = rsCash + 200000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "$200k was found!";
    break;
case 2:
    rsCash = rsCash + 25000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "$15 was found!";
    break;
case 3:
    rsCash = rsCash + 5000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "5k was found!";
    break;
case 4:
    rsCash = rsCash + 500000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "500k was found!";
    break;
case 5:
    rsCash = rsCash + 75000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "75k was found!";
    break;
case 6:
    rsCash = rsCash + 5000000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "5m was found!";
    break;
case 7:
    rsCash = rsCash + 275000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "275k was found!";
    break;
case 8:
    rsCash = rsCash + 5000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "5k was found!";
    break;
case 9:
    rsCash = rsCash + 15000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "15k was found!";
    break;
case 10:
    rsCash = rsCash + 8000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "8k was found!";
    break;
case 11:
    rsCash = rsCash + 35000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "35k was found!";
    break;
case 12:
    rsCash = rsCash + 125000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "125k was found!";
    break;
case 13:
    rsCash = rsCash + 80000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "80k was found!";
    break;
case 14:
    rsCash = rsCash + 600000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "600k was found!";
    break;
case 15:
    rsCash = rsCash + 12000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "12k was found!";
    break;

}
```

I Don't understand why the variable is returning null?

Comment: can you indicate where exactly the error occurs?

Comment: document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash + "Gp"; is where the Error occurs

Comment: `document.getElementById("cash3")` is returning `null` because it is not finding an element with that id value, either because you're running this code before the DOM has finished loading or because an element with that id simply isn't in the DOM.

Comment: There has to be a more dynamic way to do this ?

Comment: You may also want to read about the [DRY principles (Don't Repeat Yourself)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) because this code needs to be DRYed a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pointing you to this code (repeated many times):

```
document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash + "Gp";
```

The `document.getElementById("cash3")` call is returning null here.  You need to properly find your element.

You probably only need to do this:

```
var cashElement = document.getElementById("correctID");
```

Then reuse that variable throughout.

Like commenters have said, it's likely that this is because you are executing the code before the DOM is loaded.  jQuery has simple ways to handle this by placing code in `$(document).ready`, or it can be done in vanilla javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // code…
});
```

This will allow your code to run after the DOM is loading, making your code able to see the HTML and access it.

Comment: Okay there is no Error message anymore but it is still not updating the variable int he document