# Undefined is not a function for document.getElementById("Id")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I keep Getting the same Error Message "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" for having this?
The Variable is `rsCash = 5;`

```
<h1 id="RsMoney">RsCash:<b id="cash3">0 Gp</b></h1>
```

and having this javascript

```
switch (rsCash){
case 1:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash + "Gp";
    break;
case 2:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash + "Gp";
    break;
case 3:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash + "Gp";
    break;
case 4:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash.substring(0,cut1) + "k";
    break;
case 5:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash.substring(0,cut2) + "k";
```

Error Message here

```
    break;
case 6:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash.substring(0,cut3) + "k";
    break;
case 7:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash.substring(0,cut1) + "M";
    break;
case 8:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash.substring(0,cut2) + "M";
    break;
case 9:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash.substring(0,cut3) + "M";
    break;
case 10:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash.substring(0,cut4) + "M";
    break;
case 11:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash.substring(0,cut5) + "M";
    break;
```

}

Comment: You are probably accessing the element before added to DOM, put your script with script tags just before ending body tag

Comment: What is the value and `typeof` for `rsCash`?

Comment: I've just moved the  `<script src="JavaScript.js"></script>` just Above the </body> tag now but its still not working. is there another way to run the code after the DOM has loaded

Comment: rsCash is a number (according to the strict switch) and has no substring method. use String(rsCash).substring(0,cut2)

Comment: Its an integer but i wanted to convert it to a string with the toString() then do .length so the switch statement cases should be based off how long the number is.

Comment: @JohnWholey: rsCash.toString().substring should be fine too

Comment: You want the **length** of the number to be in the switch? Like this: `switch(rsCash.toString().length) { ...}`?

Comment: Is this question a duplicate of the OP's earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539435/setting-a-variable-to-a-string-returning-as-null?  Looks like the exact same code.

Comment: Dosnt matter it hadn't been fixed but now it has.

Answer (score 0):

that's mean `rsCash` don't have the method `substring` which is the type `string` had.

you can try this to type the `rsCash`:

```
`function test(a){
  switch(a){
  case 1: console.log(typeof a);break;
 }
}`
```

you can get the `number` ,not `string` , so you should change `rsCash` to `string` type